# Floofill Error Python

Tags: python, image, numpy, flood-fill

I am trying to make an algorithm in python where a random element in an (300,300,3) nd numpy image array is picked and is changed to white. Then the surrounding pixels have a 99 percent probability of being changed to white and the ones surrounding those have a 98 percent chance of being turned white and so on and so forth. I am trying to use a floodfill algorithm to achieve this but it gives me a recursion error. Any suggestions?

```
    import numpy as np
    import random

    def addHoles(a):
        randX = random.randint(0,299)
        randY = random.randint(0,299) 
        floodfill(a,randX,randY,100)



    def prob(n):
        rand = random.randint(0,101)
        if rand < n:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def floodfill(a,x,y,n):
        white = [255,255,255]

        if(x == 299 or y == 299 or x == 0 or y == 0):
            return

        if(prob(n)):
            a[x,y] = white
        floodfill(a, x+1, y, n-1)
        floodfill(a, x-1, y, n-1)
        floodfill(a, x, y+1, n-1)
        floodfill(a, x, y-1, n-1)
```

Comment: your if loop - ```if (x=300)``` did you mean to use ```==``` ?

Comment: yes i fixed that already thanks for asking

Comment: So looking at the recursion termination condition - recursion only ends when your randomly generated ints (either x or y) are 299? Is this your intended behavior?

Comment: I want the algorithm to stop when every pixel has been analyzed, so I thought stopping it once either x or y reached one of the edges was the best solution, but I don't think its right

Comment: If your intention was to stop once every pixel is analysed - then yes - you should go back to the drawing board :) This approach won't work

Comment: do you have any suggestions?